# Insert List as Column into Dataframe R

Tags: r, list

I am trying to append a column to the end of my dataframe. The column is supposed to be filled with list `id`. However, when I write `w <-cbind(w, id)`, it instead prints the entirety of `id` into each cell of the data frame.

Current output:

```
    optOne%    optTwo%    Neither%    TotalCount    id
1   20         1          1           21            A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
2   17         0          1           21            A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
3   15         2          4           21            A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
4   12         0          9           21            A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
5   18         1          2           21            A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
```

desired output:

```
    optOne%    optTwo%    Neither%    TotalCount    id
1   20         1          1           21            A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 
2   17         0          1           21            A18ACKRAVMM8D8 
3   15         2          4           21            A19JXVM2WO1CJ8
4   12         0          9           21            A1A7O3TW2O0TPM
5   18         1          2           21            A1AKB300WFZPZ3
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's hard to guess what `id` actually looks like.

Comment: `print(id)` returns: 

`[1] "A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3"`

Comment: It would appear that `id` is a character vector of length 1, not a list, nor a character vector of the same size as your dataset. Please provide a reproducible example. In doing so you may find your solution!

Comment: Arrrgh. read `?cbind.data.frame`. It does not say that lists are valid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `id` is a single string so you will need to `strsplit` it first (which outputs a list). then just add a new column using `$`

```
w$id <- unlist(strsplit(id,split=" "))
```

Comment: If `guildenstem's` data looks like the one below,  dat$id <- strsplit(dat$id, " ")[[1]]

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
 dat <- read.table(text="optOne%,optTwo%,Neither%,TotalCount,id
 1,20,1,1,21,A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
 2,17,0,1,21,A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
 3,15,2,4,21,A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
 4,12,0,9,21,A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3
 5,18,1,2,21,A1779TGH2ZMWJ2 A18ACKRAVMM8D8 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM A1AKB300WFZPZ3",
 sep=",",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F,check.names=F)

 transform(dat, id=unique(scan(text=id, what="character")))
 #Read 25 items
 #  optOne. optTwo. Neither. TotalCount             id
 #1      20       1        1         21 A1779TGH2ZMWJ2
 #2      17       0        1         21 A18ACKRAVMM8D8
 #3      15       2        4         21 A19JXVM2WO1CJ8
 # 4      12       0        9         21 A1A7O3TW2O0TPM
 #5      18       1        2         21 A1AKB300WFZPZ3
```